# Adding new set of Parameters in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to eliminate  every section name that has `'tele%'` with a `primary_facitlity = 0 ;`

The section name `'tele'` has a primary facitlity 0 and 1, I would like to keep the ones that contains `'tele'` as section and and primary facility that has 1

```
SELECT *
FROM PRACTITIONER 
    INNER JOIN PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS ON (practitioner_id_numbers.pract_id = practitioner.pract_id)
    INNER JOIN PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES ON (PRACTITIONER.PRACT_ID = PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRACT_ID)
WHERE(((PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.documentname) like 'Radio%' 
        or (PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.documentname) like 'Fluoro%') 
        and ((PRACTITIONER_ID_NUMBERS.historical)=0))
AND PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.CURRENT_STATUS = 'Current'
AND PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.FACCODE = 'LA'
/* I would like to eliminate  every section name that has 'tele%' with a primary_facitlity = 0 */ 
--AND (PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.SECTION_NAME not like 'tele%' and PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRIMARY_FACILITY = 0)
/* The end statement above does not work*/
ORDER BY PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.FACCODE;
```

Comment: Next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also try to rewrite your two first paragrah because isnt clear what are you asking.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had were to test but i think this should work. Add this constraint:

```
and (PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.PRIMARY_FACILITY = 1 or PRACTITIONER_FACILITIES.SECTION_NAME not like 'tele%')
```

Comment: The first line say want eliminate `tele and =0`, second line say want keep `tele and =1` I guess you should use only `like` and remove the `not`, But still is not clear if OP need `OR/AND`

Comment: tele with 0 = do not show in the report; tele with 1 show in the report. sorry about the confusion